# Empty collection returned with Spring JPA

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I am using JPA with Spring to retrieve a list of "Feature" from a "Role". But, when I want to retrieve this list from my application, it returns me an empty list whereas I retrieve something when I execute the generated SQL request from a SQL client

Here is my data model:

FEATURE:
- id (PK)
- name
- description

AD_ROLE:
- id (PK)
- name

FEATURE_AD_ROLE
- feature_id (FK to FEATURE.id)
- ad_role_id (FK to AD_ROLE.id)

My entities are:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FEATURE")
public class Feature implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private int id;

    private String name;
    private String description;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "FEATURE_AD_ROLE", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "FEATURE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "AD_ROLE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"))
    private Collection<ADRole> adRoles;

    // getter/setters
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "AD_ROLE")
public class ADRole implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private int id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "adRoles")
    private List<Feature> features;

    // getters/setters
}
```

My DAO:

```
@Repository
public interface FeatureDao extends JpaRepository<Feature, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT f FROM Feature f JOIN f.adRoles fa WHERE fa.name = :adProfile")
    public Collection<Feature> getFeaturesByADProfile(@Param("adProfile") String adProfile);

}
```

This generates this SQL request:

```
select feature0_.id as id1_1_, feature0_.description as description2_1_, feature0_.name as name3_1_ from FEATURE feature0_ inner join FEATURE_AD_ROLE adroles1_ on feature0_.id=adroles1_.FEATURE_ID inner join AD_ROLE adrole2_ on adroles1_.AD_ROLE_ID=adrole2_.id where adrole2_.name=?
```

When I execute this request from a SQL client, I can see a result.

My DBMS is Oracle.

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, never mind. This morning, I found out that it was because I added entries from my SQL client and I did not commit the transaction. :(

This is just... awkward.

Comment: I'm new to using Oracle databases. Having used MySQL earlier, this was a new feature i didnt catch while referring tutorials. Your answer made me look more into the Oracle Documentation regarding committing work.  Sharing the documentation link in case if anyone else faces the same issue and wastes a lot of time without knowing what's going on. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4010.htm